# Allocated memory does not take value it is assigned

Tags: c, malloc

I've been searching this forum for hours trying to find an answer to my question, read the man page, and can't seem to see anything wrong with what I'm doing.

This is what's happening. I have a program that loops through and adds entries to a (graph) adjacency matrix if the distances between two objects are small enough. If they aren't small enough to be added to the adjacency matrix, if they aren't too big, it should add the coordinates of the entry to a list of coordinate pairs, called "possible_edgelist."

My problem is "possible_edgelist" doesn't take on the values I assign it (i and j to its entries 0 and 1). HOWEVER the two commands on either side of the assignment are being executed. I'll paste some example output after the code:

```
uncertain_edge_max = 4;
certain_edge_max = 3.2;


printmatrix(shelldistmtx, shellsize, shellsize); //this is being generated correctly. 

max_num_of_edges = shellsize*(shellsize-1)/2; 

possible_edgelist=(int**)malloc(max_num_of_edges* sizeof(int*));
for(i=0; i<max_num_of_edges; i++)
{
    possible_edgelist[i] = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
}

poss_edge_num = 0;

for(i=0; i<shellsize; i++)
{
    adjacency_matrix[i][i]=0;
    for(j=i+1; j<shellsize; j++)
    {
        if (shelldistmtx[i][j]<=certain_edge_max) {

            adjacency_matrix[i][j]= 1;
            adjacency_matrix[j][i]= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(shelldistmtx[i][j] <= uncertain_edge_max)
            {
                printf("%d \t %d \t %d \t %lf \n", poss_edge_num, i, j, shelldistmtx[i][j]); 
                // ^this is being executed 


                //*****THESE TWO LINES ARE NOT BEING EXECUTED???*********
                possible_edgelist[poss_edge_num][0]=i;
                possible_edgelist[poss_edge_num][1]=j;
                poss_edge_num=poss_edge_num + 1; //this is being executed

            }
            adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 0;
            adjacency_matrix[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    adjacency_matrix[i][shellsize] = 1;
    adjacency_matrix[shellsize][i] = 1;
}


//troubleshooting output

for (i=0; i<poss_edge_num; i++)
{
    printf("%d, %d \n", possible_edgelist[poss_edge_num][0], possible_edgelist[poss_edge_num][1]); //this outputs zeros and bizarre numbers.
}
```

Now, for the output I get:

```
0.000000    3.535534    3.535534    4.960403    4.960403    
3.535534    0.000000    5.000000    3.715589    3.715589    
3.535534    5.000000    0.000000    3.715589    3.715589    
4.960403    3.715589    3.715589    0.000000    3.400000    
4.960403    3.715589    3.715589    3.400000    0.000000    
0    0   1   3.535534 
1    0   2   3.535534 
2    1   3   3.715589 
3    1   4   3.715589 
4    2   3   3.715589  
5    2   4   3.715589 
6    3   4   3.400000 
0, -1073741824 
0, -1073741824 
0, -1073741824 
0, -1073741824 
0, -1073741824 
0, -1073741824 
0, -1073741824
```

The last set of values should be (0, 1), (0,2), (1,3), etc. I have no idea why the values are not bein assigned correctly, can someone please explain what is happening here?

The only thign i can think of is that this is occurring in a function that is called multiple times in rapid succession, but I have been sure to free() everything in here that changes with each function call before returning, (and the things that don't change, were allocated/freed outside the function).

Oh, and yes, I've tried calloc() too. Same problem, except all 0's.

Help!

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  Code doesn't just "not get executed" without some conditional statement.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that with gcc in the terminal? There were also no compile warnings.

Comment: Why are you casting the return from `malloc()`?

Comment: I was told it was a good habit? It seemed to be something people disagree on, so I do the one that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printing forl loop has mistake:

```
for (i=0; i<poss_edge_num; i++)
{
    printf("%d, %d \n", possible_edgelist[i][0], possible_edgelist[i][1]);
}
```